# Constructing a simple regex, with only +, *, (), and |

Tags: pcre

Let `{a,b,c}` be the alphabet. I have to construct a regex that matches any input over this alphabet, and if `aa` appears in the input, then `cc` must appear as well (somewhere in the input).

No look ahead, no look behind, no backreferences, just by using the quantifiers + and *, grouping via parentheses and alternatives via `|`.

The problem is I don't know how to approach this. For instance these inputs must match:

- abba
- bccb
- bccaa
- "" (empty input)
- bccbaa
- ccbaabb

The following must not match:

- aa
- abaaab
- baaa
- caac

How can I construct such a regex, using only these tools?

**Update**

I have thought about

```
((cc(b|c)*aa)|(aa(b|c)*cc))+|(ab|ba|ca|ca|bb|bc|cc)*
```

What do you think, does this fulfill the specification?

Comment: 1>how many occurance of a and c should be there so that they match..2>Do you want only a,c to be repeated and not others 3>your question is **ambiguous** and **very** `confusing`..try to improve your question

Comment: Ok, let's imagine such regex does exist, it's anchorless and it matches some string A. Tell me, how do you expect this anchorless regex NOT to match string A + 'd'? 'd' + A? In fact, I suppose any normal (=no atomics/possessives) regex that should match an empty string will match _any_ string given, in the end.

Comment: @raina77ow: The constraints on the problem here are consistent with the type of regexes they teach about in school.  Those are defined so that the entire character set only has a certain set of symbols, in this case [abc].  And they're already anchored at both ends.

Comment: Re: your update: The expression would match `baab`, and fail on `a`.  If there must always be an even number of chars, disregard that last part -- but that should be in the specification, if it's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more-o-less trivial for the given set of params, I suppose:

```
/^((b|c|ab|ac|a$)*|(a|b|c)*(cc(a|b|c)*aa|aa(a|b|c)*cc)(a|b|c)*)$/;
```

Explanation: obviously you need to match for three cases here:

- the whole string doesn't contain 'aa' sequence. This condition is expressed with the following pattern:

`/^(b|c|ab|ac|a$)*$/`

...that is: "match any number of any combination of `b` and `c` symbols, `ab`, `ac` sequences or single `a` item at the end of the string".

- the whole string does contain 'aa' sequence, followed (somewhere) by 'cc' sequence - and it's still composed of `[abc]` range only:

  `/^(a|b|c)* aa(a|b|c)* cc(a|b|c)* $/`

(somehow without whitespace `*` are treated as italic text markers even within the `<code>` section; you obviously don't need it in the regex)

- the whole string does contain 'aa' sequence, preceded (somewhere) by 'cc' sequence - and it's still composed of `[abc]` range only:

  `/^(a|b|c)* cc(a|b|c)* aa(a|b|c)* $/`

Now you have three parts of the regex, and it's quite easy to combine it into the simple pattern, I suppose.

Comment: There are no `^` and `$` :-(. Please see my update.

Comment: Accepted, I have thought about the same (either there is some `aa` or it's not, but if it is, then it can be either preceeded or followed by `cc` with some optional `abc` combinations in-between), but not having `$` and `^` has locked me down. Not sure though if we're allowed to use `$` in the middle of the rule (`^` is implicitly at the beginning and `$` is implicitly at the end). In this context, *look aheads* look like a nice dream :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
(b|c|a(b|c))*(a|)|(a|b|c)*(aa(a|b|c)*cc|cc(a|b|c)*aa)(a|b|c)*
```

Will match:

- Any number of `b`s or `c`s (even zero), or an `a` if followed by a `b` or `c`, plus an optional unaccompanied `a` at the end.  These rules together ensure that two `a`s are always separated by a `b` or `c`, and will match the empty string and single chars as well.
- A string that includes an aa somewhere, followed eventually by a cc
- A string that includes a cc somewhere, followed eventually by an aa

(For reference, if you need each `aa` to match up with a `cc`, you're kinda screwed.  That's no longer regular.  A string like `ccccaaaa` would require counting how many `cc`s have been seen so far, and FSAs can't count.)

Comment: It will match 'aa' as well.

Comment: How?  Two `a`s can never appear side by side unless the expression finds a `cc` as well.

Comment: Ah, damn, forgot to wrap it all in its own set of parenthesis (so the final pattern will look like /^(...)$/. Sorry.